# Average of a unicode list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following list:

```
prices = [u'2.24', u'$2.24', u'$2.24', u'$2.24', u'$2.21']
```

I would like to get the average of the list and have attempted the following:

```
avgPrice = sum(prices) / float(len(prices))
```

However, for some reason I get the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'
```

I don't understand why unicode is causing a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your prices are strings, not numbers. You should first strip them of the $ signs, then convert them to floats. Only then may you sum them and divide the total.

```
prices = [u'2.24', u'$2.24', u'$2.24', u'$2.24', u'$2.21']

prices = [float(price.replace('$', '')) for price in prices]

mean = sum(prices)/len(prices)

print(mean)
# 2.2340000000000004
```

Comment: What are the letter "u"s for?